# Cant connect to Mysql in JAVA

Tags: java, android, mysql

Is giving error when I try to connect to mysql with java / android

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
```

**ERROR:
Could not create connection to database server.**

```
10-28 18:25:05.621: D/AbsListView(20635): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-28 18:25:05.626: E/MYSQL(20635): Erro: Could not create connection to database server.
10-28 18:25:05.626: E/MYSQL(20635): Erro: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-28 18:25:05.626: W/System.err(20635): Got an exception! 
10-28 18:25:05.626: W/System.err(20635): Could not create connection to database server.
10-28 18:25:05.636: E/MYSQL(20635): Erro: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**MAIN:**

```
    //Conectar no Banco
    conn = new ConnectMysql();
    try {
        conn.getConexato();

    } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("MYSQL", "Erro: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

**ConnectMysql:**

```
 public Connection getConexato() throws ClassNotFoundException,  
    SQLException, java.sql.SQLException, InstantiationException,  
    IllegalAccessException {  

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  

    conn = (Connection)     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql.hostinger.com.br:3306/u917553846_123","u917553846_admin","teste123");  

    return conn;  
}
```

Comment: Add the stacktrace to your error log: `Log.e(e);` That will give you more information as to where the `NullPointerException` is being thrown

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if the Android app has the correct permissions for accessing services on the Internet.

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Yes, have permission INTERNET

Comment: Ok, are you able to resolve the hostname, e.g. via `nslookup`?

Comment: nslookuo? do not know

Comment: It is `nslookup mysql.hostinger.com.br`. Could be possible that a DNS entry is missing, so that the hostname can not be resolved to an IP.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql.hostinger.com.br` is non-existent domain. Are you sure about the address to your db ?